# An html box with a title and an edit button

Tags: html, css

I've made this html box, that is supposed to have a title and some buttons on right,

http://jsfiddle.net/vqpmt/17/

Everything seems fine except that the edit button as you can see is a little bit below the title, that shouldn't be the case they should both be at the same exact level.

How do I achieve that, and is my code a mess? Is there a better way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved h1 and the edit link tag inside a div container. Check my version of your code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/vqpmt/29/)**

To be on the exact same level, the html elements has to be either inside a container (as in my fiddle) or should use 2 inline html elements.

Try reading w3schools on html and css which has lot of information that you can learn in short time.

w3schools HTML reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

w3schools CSS reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

**Edit:** h1 is a block element which means it will add a new line. So I added a new css style `.inline` and changed the block property to inline.

```
.inline { display: inline }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your H1 element extends the width of the page and is pushing your edit link down. I've provided an alternative solution here.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GvGoldmedal/vqpmt/32/